# os.path.getmtime returning negative number only in Windows Server

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, windows-server, oserror

I'm writing a python script in Windows server where I need the modified time of my file in a folder path.

```
filestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path+filename))
```

My code works fine locally but when I test in Windows Server, datetime.fromtimestamp returns

> OSError : [Errno 22] Invalid argument

so when I print `os.path.getmtime(path+filename)`, it returns `-11623064500.963923`

This is obviously wrong to convert to datetime and it only happens when in Windows Server.

I have seen answers multiplying / dividing the value by 1000, but it's no use. Especially when the value is negative.

Is there are alternate ways to get modified datetime of a file?

Comment: Tried os.stat().st_mtime as well but same return value.

Comment: What it is the real date (that you see with Microsoft tools)?

Comment: "Strangely", if you assume it is correct, it give you a date in 1601, and Microsoft start with such years on some structures (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime), so maybe it is just a unknown date

Comment: The files are last modified within the last few months. Seems like the value is totally invalid as reported by datetime.fromtimestamp : OSError : [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: It was not my question. What is the date reported by Microsoft tools (e.g. dir or fileExplorer)? We cannot debut things if we miss the initial status. "modified" doesn't matter: tools may forget to update such field, or just the filesystem is configured not to save modification dates (for performance reasons), or the mounting option are set to ignore such field (because not all file system have good data), or on reproducible environment libraries will lie about time, etc. Never trust your assumptions. And because my second comment, I think it is the API which report such date(not python error)

Comment: Sorry, you were right. After checking the properties, the file indeed had an old date like 1601. There is no python issue, I will close this question

Comment: Do not close the question. It could be interesting for other people. In fact I saw the 1601 only on Microsoft doc, but not in any bug reports or here in stack overflow, so other people may get some info in this page